# How do I reduce variable by 5%?

Tags: python, function, while-loop

As a man runs up a slope he rushes until he runs out of energy than stops to take a break, the function returns how many times he rushes up the slope untill he gets to the top.  Each time he rushes again he loses 5 %.  However when I run this programme it takes too long and doesn't return anything.  It should return 19.

```
    def num_rushes(slope_height, rush_height_gain, back_sliding):
        current_height = 0
        rushes = 0
        while current_height < slope_height:
            current_height += rush_height_gain
            if current_height < slope_height:
                current_height -= back_sliding
            rushes += 1
            rush_height_gain = rush_height_gain * 0.95  
        return rushes

    ans = num_rushes(100, 15, 7)
    print(ans)
```

Comment: I would recommend adding some print statements to your loop to see how the values are changing after each iteration, and see what is going wrong. You're not doing anything with the `back_sliding` variable, so maybe you forgot to do part of the problem.

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you are running? I copied & pasted it and almost instantly got 8 as output.

Comment: When I run this in my Python 3.5.3 it ends very quickly and prints `8`. Of course, I fixed the indentation before I ran it. Do you really have all those spaces in front of each line?

Comment: I added back in the back_sliding bit.  This just minuses the amount they slide backwards after they have stopped.  I took it out because I didnt think that would have been the issue and wanted to keep question as simple as possible.  However now im more confused.

Comment: As the climber decelerates, its net speed might actually become negative (`rush_height_gain - back_sliding < 0`). How will you account for that?

Answer (score 0):

Whats happening is that your height gain is constant (15), and during the loop you slide back by some constant (7) as long as you're not at the top. So you would think that you'd just slowly climb the slope to the top because the gain is greater than the slide back

However, each iteration of the loop you're reducing the value of height gain to 95% of its value (i.e. you're gaining less and less each iteration). This is fine, and you'll keep climbing, but as soon as the height gain value becomes less than the slide back value you'll just keep sliding into negative values of current height and the loop will never exit

Comment: I'd even add that log(7/15)/log(0.95) = 14.86... so after 14 rushes you will start going down :)